# I need to set a divs max-width to device-width

Tags: html, css

I have a div that only works properly when I set its max width for scrolling.  I want to be able to set its max-width in css to the device width, is this possible?  using something like viewport.width or something?

Comment: you can use 100VW. Width 100% should work though as long as there is content (height). You can best achieve this with a wrapper concept. After your body tag, make a div with id wrapper and give it 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
div{
  vw: 100;
}
```

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 1vh = 1% of viewport height
>
> 1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller 1
>
> vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you should be able to set max to %100. If the div is nested you can set position absolute.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.not-nested {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.nested {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.half {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Not Nested</h1>
<div class="not-nested">This dis has a max width of 100% and the text in it will wrap as it goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on.</div>

<h1>Nested</h1>
<div class="half">
  <div class="nested">This dis has a max width of 100% and the text in it will wrap as it goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's actually setting the right size when i do this, but then the div box floats over top the <p> items that surround it... if i take off position: abosolute it doesn't size correctly..

Comment: Can you post some code so I can see what you are doing?